# Is one singular nucleus with no help whatsoever powerful enough?

Tags: nuclear-physics, explosions

A dude has the power to split a nucleus. But this nucleus doesn't hit anything, it just explodes, and that's that. He explodes the atom. He can let the nucleus explode, or he can absorb it. I was making this character thinking he could just split an nucleus, and it would make a nuke-level explosion, and then he could absorb the power of a nuke. But is ONE SINGULAR nucleus splitting, with NO help whatsoever, would that ONE singular nucleus explode with the force of a nuke?

Answer (score 3):

One single atom of Uranium 235, one of the heaviest atoms, weighs as the name implies 235 Daltons, or about $4\times 10^{-25}$ kg. Even if all this rest mass were released as energy via $E=mc^2$, this would amount to a maximum of $4\times 10^{-8}$ Joules of energy, which is roughly the kinetic energy of a gnat in flight.  So nowhere near a nuke.

The power of nukes comes from creating a chain reaction of on the order of $10^{26}$ atomic fission events, like having a football field covered in mouse traps, and setting off one mousetrap creates a cascading chain of events.

Comment: Sure, except that, when a Uranium atom "explodes" in reality, only a minuscule fraction of its rest mass disappears. The combined mass of the fragments and free neutrons is only slightly less than the mass of the original atom. The actual amount of energy released is around 200 MeV—roughly three orders of magnitude smaller than your $4×10^{-8}$ Joule. So, something more like the kinetic energy of the gnat's pinky toe. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission

Comment: You're correct. I was demonstrating the maximum possible energy contained in the atom as an illustration.

Answer (score 1):

No. The energy released by the decay of any individual nucleus is incredibly small by human standards.

Low-level radioactive decay is everywhere - in rocks, in the atmosphere, and in your body.  If the decay of a single nucleus (by any means, fission or otherwise) resulted in an explosion comparable to modern nuclear weapons, then the universe would be ... somewhat more hostile.